# How to use signal blocking in Ruby

Tags: ruby, signals

How does one block certain signals in Ruby? (I.e. sigprocmask, as described here: http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_21.html#SEC371)

Here is my example code

```
pid = fork do
  trap('INT') do
    puts "Graceful shutdown..."
    puts "goodbye"
    exit 0
  end

  loop do
    this_could_be_interrupted
    something_that_must_not_be_interrupted
    this_could_be_interrupted_too
  end
end

sleep 5
Process.kill('INT', pid)
```

Can I wrap `something_that_must_not_be_interrupted` in a ruby block or something to ensure that SIGINT won't be process while that method is running?

I guess the ideal would be if I could do something like this:

```
Process.block_signal('INT') do
  something_that_must_not_be_interrupted
end
```

**UPDATE**: I'm currently doing something like this:

```
trap('INT') do
  @interrupted = true
end

loop do
  exit 0 if @interrupted
  something_that_must_not_be_interrupted
end
```

Comment: Just as a follow up, Ruby does **not** handle this for you. For example I have had an Errno::EINTR raise on this line: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `initialize'. If Ruby let you block signals, that HTTP request would not be interrupted.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [non-block form of `trap`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Signal.html#method-c-trap):

> `Signal.trap( signal, command ) → obj`
>   [...]
>   If the command is the string `"IGNORE"` or `"SIG_IGN"`, the signal will be ignored. If the command is `"DEFAULT"` or `"SIG_DFL"`, the Ruby‘s default handler will be invoked.

So you should be able to say this:

```
trap('INT', 'IGNORE')
something_that_must_not_be_interrupted
trap('INT', 'DEFAULT')
```

---

**UPDATE**: From the comments, it looks like you only want to temporarily ignore the signal. The easiest way to do that with what you already have is to add a flag that your signal handler can see, then remember the signal when it comes in and we're currently ignoring the signal, and when we're not ignoring things anymore you just empty the signal queue by sending them to yourself. If wrap this logic up in a class, you'll have something fairly friendly:

```
#
# Threading and race condition issues are left as an exercise,
# this is just meant as an illustration. Handling multiple signals
# at once is also left as an exercise.
#
class SignalHandler
  def initialize(signal)
    @interuptable = true
    @enqueued     = [ ]
    trap(signal) do
      if(@interuptable)
        puts "Graceful shutdown..."
        puts "goodbye"
        exit 0
      else
        @enqueued.push(signal)
      end
    end
  end

  # If this is called with a block then the block will be run with
  # the signal temporarily ignored. Without the block, we'll just set
  # the flag and the caller can call `allow_interuptions` themselves.
  def dont_interupt
    @interuptable = false
    @enqueued     = [ ]
    if(block_given?)
      yield
      allow_interuptions
    end
  end

  def allow_interuptions
    @interuptable = true
    # Send the temporarily ignored signals to ourself,
    # see http://ruby-doc.org/core/Process.html#method-c-kill
    @enqueued.each { |signal| Process.kill(signal, 0) }
  end
end
```

The real functional code was the easiest way to explain the technique (and I had to write it anyway to make sure the technique would work) so there you go. And thanks for the review of signal handling in Ruby :) Then you could so things like this:

```
sigint = SignalHandler.new('INT')
loop do
  this_could_be_interrupted
  sigint.dont_interupt { something_that_must_not_be_interrupted }
  this_could_be_interrupted_too
end
```

Comment: shouldn't the last `trap` be `trap('INT', 'DEFAULT')`?

Comment: @Simon: Yes it should have been `INT` and now it is :) Thanks.

Comment: My understanding was that this technique causes the program to act as if the signal never happened. Is that not the case? I have bits of code that should not be interrupted by a signal; however, the signals still need to be processed. When those bits of code finish running, the signal should be processed.

Comment: I guess that is closer to what I was looking for. However, the code I don't want to get interrupted, is still interrupted. The exit doesn't happen until after that code finishes, but the signal is still processed in the middle of the "non-interruptable" code. That leaves me with a question (and maybe this was the real question): is this safe? I know there are situations in C programs where this is not safe. Does Ruby "just work" in this case? Do I even need to worry about truly blocking the signals?

Comment: Also, please see my update. I think what I am currently doing is quite similar (effectively) to what you have suggested. I.e. process the signal immediately, but don't do the work (i.e. exiting) until the uninterruptable code has finished running.

Comment: @phylae: Yeah, the SignalHandler class approach is a more elaborate way of setting a flag (a better SignalHandler would take a block to call when the signal is caught). If you want to emulate POSIX signal handling completely, I think you'd have to build a C extension and quite possibly hack the signal handling inside the Ruby interpreter. You'd probably need to review threading issues as well.

Comment: I think @interuptable should be set to true in the initializer. Otherwise, signals are ignored and never handled up until the first use of dont_interupt. Other than that, thanks this example was very helpful.

Comment: @kstevens715: But `@interuptable` isn't checked until the signal handler's block is evaluated and that doesn't happen until the signal is triggered. Or am I missing something? This is answer is a couple years old after all so you're probably more familiar with it than I am right now :)

Comment: @muistooshort `@interuptable` is also checked when a signal is trapped which could occur anytime after initialize. So by defaulting it to false, it indeed is not interruptable during the block, but it also isn't interruptable /before/ the block. After the block it is interruptable again.

Comment: @kstevens715: I see what you're saying and I think you're right about the initial `@interuptable` value. Sorry about taking so long, putting your head two years in the past isn't always easy (which is why all programmers should start out doing maintenance :).

Answer (score 6):

Ruby returns the last handler associated with the signal, so you can use:

```
def bypass_signal(name)
  old_handler = trap("INT", 'IGNORE')
  yield
  trap("INT", old_handler)
end

bypass_signal "INT" { method_which_shouldnt_be_interrupted }
```

Comment: Blocking signals and ignoring signals are quite different. Your example simply drops the signal. That means that any signals my process receives while running `method_which_shouldnt_be_interrupted` will never get processed. This is not the desired behavior. In C, sigprocmask will queue up any signals while they are blocked. Once they are no longer blocked, those signals will be sent. With sigprocmask, no signals are lost.

Comment: This would also benefit from a begin ... ensure around yield.